# Cannot invoke method with argument list of type KeyType in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I am working on custom message dispatcher in Swift. I want to have dispatcher which can:

- dispatch enums as events or whatever what is `Hashable`.
- Every object which implements one protocol might be added as listeners

Here is the code:

```
import Foundation

protocol EventDispatcherProtocol: class {
    typealias T: Hashable
    func dispatcherDidDispatchEvent(event: T)
}

class EventListenerWrapper<T: EventDispatcherProtocol> {
    weak var object: T?

    init(_ object: T) {
        self.object = object
    }
}

class EventDispatcher<KeyType: Hashable, U: EventDispatcherProtocol> {
    private var objects = Dictionary<KeyType, [EventListenerWrapper<U>]>()

    func add(#listener: U, forEvent event: KeyType) {
        let wrapper = EventListenerWrapper(object: listener)

        // get all wrappers
        if let storedWrappers = objects[event] {
            // check if there is such objects already wrapped for this type of event
            var found = false
            for storedWrapper in storedWrappers {
                if let storedObject = storedWrapper.object
                where (storedObject as! AnyObject) === (wrapper.object as! AnyObject) {
                    // Found it!
                    found = true
                    break
                }
            }

            if found == false {
                // If not found then add the wrapper for this event
                var updatedWrappers = storedWrappers
                updatedWrappers.append(wrapper)
                self.objects[event] = updatedWrappers
            }

        } else {
            self.objects[event] = [wrapper]
        }
    }

    func dispatch(event: KeyType) {
        // Enumerate through wrappers
        if let storedWrappers = objects[event] {
            var idxToRemove = [Int]()

            var currentIdx = 0
            for storedWrapper in storedWrappers {
                // if there is object to dispatch - dispatch message
                // otherwise add index of this object to remove wrapper later
                if let storedObject = storedWrapper.object {
//                    storedObject.dispatcherDidDispatchEvent(event) /// <- cannot invoke 'this method'  with an argument list of type '(KeyType)'
                } else {
                    idxToRemove.append(currentIdx)
                }

                currentIdx++
            }

            // enumerate through reversed array of indexes to remove
            // and remove items, update wrappers at the end.
            idxToRemove = idxToRemove.reverse()
            var updatedWrappers = storedWrappers
            for idx in idxToRemove {
                updatedWrappers.removeAtIndex(idx)
            }

            objects[event] = updatedWrappers
        }
    }
}



// EXAMPLE

enum CustomEvent {
    case Start, Stop
}

class CustomListener: EventDispatcherProtocol {
    func dispatcherDidDispatchEvent(event: CustomEvent) {
        println("CustomListener heard that event! \(event)")
    }
}

// Create listeners and wrap them
var listener1 = CustomListener()
var listener2 = CustomListener()

// Create dispatcher
var dispatcher = EventDispatcher<CustomEvent, CustomListener>()
dispatcher.add(listener: listener1, forEvent: CustomEvent.Start)
dispatcher.add(listener: listener2, forEvent: CustomEvent.Stop)

dispatcher.dispatch(CustomEvent.Start)
dispatcher.dispatch(CustomEvent.Stop)
```

Unfortunately there is an error in `object.dispatcherDidDispatchEvent(event)` call. I cannot understand what is wrong with this. It looks correctly for me.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT** - Working solution after @Tobol suggestion

```
import Foundation

protocol EventDispatcherProtocol {
    typealias T: Hashable
    func dispatcherDidDispatchEvent(event: T)
}

class EventListenerWrapper<T: EventDispatcherProtocol> {
    var object: T?

    init(_ object: T) {
        self.object = object
    }
}

class EventDispatcher<U: EventDispatcherProtocol> {
    typealias KeyType = U.T
    private var objects = Dictionary<KeyType, [EventListenerWrapper<U>]>()

    func add(#listener: U, forEvent event: KeyType) {
        let wrapper = EventListenerWrapper(listener)
        // get all wrappers
        if let storedWrappers = objects[event] {
            // check if there is such objects already wrapped for this type of event
            // and if not found add the wrapper for this event
            if storedWrappers.filter({($0.object as? AnyObject) === (listener as! AnyObject) }).count == 0 {
                objects[event] = storedWrappers + [wrapper]
            }

        } else {
            objects[event] = [wrapper]
        }
    }

    func dispatch(event: KeyType) {
        // Enumerate through wrappers
        if var storedWrappers = objects[event] {
            // Enumerate through stored wrappers and get indexes of objects to remove
            var indexesToRemove = [Int]()
            var currentIndex = 0
            storedWrappers.filter({
                var match = $0.object == nil
                if match { indexesToRemove.append(currentIndex) }
                currentIndex++
                return match
            })

            // Reverse array of indexes to make removing process easier
            for index in indexesToRemove.reverse() {
                storedWrappers.removeAtIndex(index)
            }

            // Dispatch message on existing objects
            for wrapper in storedWrappers {
                wrapper.object!.dispatcherDidDispatchEvent(event)
            }

            objects[event] = storedWrappers
        }
    }
}



// EXAMPLE
enum CustomEvent {
    case Start, Stop
}

class CustomListener: EventDispatcherProtocol {
    func dispatcherDidDispatchEvent(event: CustomEvent) {
        println("CustomListener heard that event! \(event)")
    }
}

// Create listeners and wrap them
var listener1 = CustomListener()

// Create dispatcher
var dispatcher = EventDispatcher<CustomListener>()
dispatcher.add(listener: listener1, forEvent: CustomEvent.Start)
dispatcher.dispatch(CustomEvent.Start)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that best solution for your case would be changing class declaration to:

```
class EventDispatcher<U: EventDispatcherProtocol> {
    typealias KeyType = U.T
```

And it will also simplify creation of the EventDispatcher with skipping the redundant type declarations:

```
var dispatcher = EventDispatcher<CustomListener<CustomEvent>>()
```

**EDIT:**
Since the code was altered multiple times while writing the answer I am attaching whole solution code example:

```
import Foundation

protocol EventDispatcherProtocol {
    typealias T: Hashable
    func dispatcherDidDispatchEvent(event: T)
}

class EventListenerWrapper<T: EventDispatcherProtocol> {
    var object: T?

    init(object: T) {
        self.object = object
    }
}

class EventDispatcher<U: EventDispatcherProtocol> {
    typealias KeyType = U.T

    private var objects = Dictionary<KeyType, [EventListenerWrapper<U>]>()

    func add(#listener: U, forEvent event: KeyType) {
        let wrapper = EventListenerWrapper(object: listener)

        // get all wrappers
        if let storedWrappers = objects[event] {
            // check if there is such objects already wrapped for this type of event
            var found = false
            for storedWrapper in storedWrappers {
                if let storedObject = storedWrapper.object
                    where (storedObject as! AnyObject) === (wrapper.object as! AnyObject) {
                        // Found it!
                        found = true
                        break
                }
            }

            if found == false {
                // If not found then add the wrapper for this event
                var updatedWrappers = storedWrappers
                updatedWrappers.append(wrapper)
                self.objects[event] = updatedWrappers
            }

        } else {
            self.objects[event] = [wrapper]
        }
    }

    func dispatch(event: KeyType) {
        // Enumerate through wrappers
        if let storedWrappers = objects[event] {
            var idxToRemove = [Int]()

            var currentIdx = 0
            for storedWrapper in storedWrappers {
                // if there is object to dispatch - dispatch message
                // otherwise add index of this object to remove wrapper later
                if let storedObject = storedWrapper.object {
                    storedObject.dispatcherDidDispatchEvent(event) /// <- cannot invoke 'this method'  with an argument list of type '(KeyType)'
                } else {
                    idxToRemove.append(currentIdx)
                }

                currentIdx++
            }

            // enumerate through reversed array of indexes to remove
            // and remove items, update wrappers at the end.
            idxToRemove = idxToRemove.reverse()
            var updatedWrappers = storedWrappers
            for idx in idxToRemove {
                updatedWrappers.removeAtIndex(idx)
            }

            objects[event] = updatedWrappers
        }
    }
}



// EXAMPLE

enum CustomEvent {
    case Start, Stop
}

class CustomListener<T: Hashable>: EventDispatcherProtocol {
    func dispatcherDidDispatchEvent(event: T) {
        println("CustomListener heard that event! \(event)")
    }
}

// Create listeners and wrap them
var listener1 = CustomListener<CustomEvent>()
var listener2 = CustomListener<CustomEvent>()

// Create dispatcher
var dispatcher = EventDispatcher<CustomListener<CustomEvent>>()
dispatcher.add(listener: listener1, forEvent: CustomEvent.Start)
dispatcher.add(listener: listener2, forEvent: CustomEvent.Stop)

dispatcher.dispatch(CustomEvent.Start)
dispatcher.dispatch(CustomEvent.Stop)
```

Comment: Thanks. I started messing around U.T and almost did it before you answered. Thanks anyway for moving me directly to this ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
storedObject.dispatcherDidDispatchEvent(event) /// <- cannot invoke 'this method'  with an argument list of type '(KeyType)'
```

`event` here is of type `KeyType` which is a generic type constrained by `Hashable`.

`dispatcherDidDispatchEvent()` takes an argument of type `CustomEvent`. That's not equivalent to "the hashable type that `EventDispatcher` was specialized over."

One of these needs to change.

Comment: Rob Napier, isn't CustomEvent enum hashable by default?

Comment: Being hashable is not the same as "the hashable type that `EventDispatcher` was specialized over."